# SQL Update case clause support by jOOQ

Tags: case, jooq

Please advise if there is a support for case clause in SQL update statement by jOOQ library? https://www.jooq.org/ I mean what would be the equivalent for

```
UPDATE TABLE1 SET status = case 
            when status = 'status1' then 'status2'
            when status = 'status2' then 'status3'
            end
```

I saw examples for select statement in their tutorial but non for update unfortunately. Could it be something like?

```
DSL.update(DSL.table("table1")).set(DSL.field("status"), DSL.case(...))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily, there's no difference between `SELECT` or `UPDATE` statement support in jOOQ with respect to how arbitrary [column expressions](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/) are dealt with. Hence, you will just use the [`CASE` expression support](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/case-expressions/) in your statement.

You can create a `CASE` expression using [`DSL.case_()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#case_(org.jooq.Field)) or [`DSL.when()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#when(org.jooq.Condition,org.jooq.Field)) directly.

Comment: How can we construct it in a loop e.g. if we have a list?

Comment: @NikolaMihajlović: Yes. I'll be happy to answer a new question with details

Comment: I was able to do it `DSL.case_().value(...).mapValues(...)` if someone finds this :)

Comment: @NikolaMihajlović: Great to know! If you want to help future visitors (which might be yourself!) you could ask *and* answer your own question here on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions